# empty initialized javascript object contains lots of properties and function

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular 8. In a component, I have this function

```
  private build(obj1: object, obj2: object) {
    const result: object = {};
    console.log('begin result');
    console.log(result);
    console.log('end result');
```

In firebug I can see the following output

[image]

[image]

As you can see there are properties and functions in the normally empty object. Why ? I just can tell you that the properties are the ones of a FormGroup that I use in this component

```
  private build(obj1: object, obj2: object) {
    const result: object = {};
    console.log('begin result');
    console.log(result);
    console.log('end result');
    for (const property in obj1) {
      console.log('property in obj1');
      console.log(property);
      console.log(result);
      result[property] = obj1[property];
      console.log(result);
    }
    for (const property in obj2) {
      console.log('property in obj2');
      console.log(property);
      if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(property) && obj2[property]) {
          result[property] = obj2[property];
        } else {
          result[property] = '';
        }
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Do you do something else with `result` after the 3 `console.log` statements? If so, can we see that code?

Comment: Hi ConnorsFan, I updated the post with the relevant information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Firebug, but I'm assuming that it's saving a reference to the `result` object, not cloning it for the purpose of logging, and so all the properties that get added after the `console.log` will still get displayed when you expand it in the logs. To check, try:

```js
console.log('begin result');
console.log(Object.keys(result));
console.log('end result');
```

This will show you all the keys attached to `result` at that instance in time.